# Como se cria textura de neve e particulas no Unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine

Estou tentando criar um mapa onde é cheio de neve, porém, eu não consegui achar nenhum tutorial em português, ou até mesmo um tutorial em inglês, que seja bem explicativo.

Pretendo colocar partículas de neve simulando uma tempestade. Também quero conseguir colisões com a neve que cai no chão.

Se alguém tiver alguma dica ou tutorial, eu agradeço.

Comment: Na própria documentação do Unreal Engine tem instruções de como criar neve e efeitos relacionados: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/Showcases/Effects/SnowExamples/index.html

Answer (score 1):

### Neve no Unreal Engine 4

Para criar o efeito que quer, é usado o **Cascade** e o **Particle Systems**.

O efeito nevasca (Blizzard) é um `GPU Sprite Particle System` composto de um aumento significativo de pequenas partículas usando um `Lit Translucent Material`.

[image]

Leia mais (documentação em inglês), [clique](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/Showcases/Effects/SnowExamples/)